# ufw has no effect when enabled

Tags: firewall, ufw

I'm messing around with `ufw`, since i've never maintained `iptables` knowledge long enough to be effective.

So, on a fresh Ubuntu LTS16, as `root`, I tried to issue some commands, similar to this list.

```
ufw default deny incoming
ufw allow ssh
ufw deny http
ufw deny https
ufw enable
```

So, here's what I got:

```
root@dev:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
27017                      DENY        Anywhere
80                         DENY        Anywhere
443                        DENY        Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27017 (v6)                 DENY        Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    DENY        Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

Yet, I can still do everything.  I can see it's webpage.  I can telnet into port 80, and talk to the webserver.  I've rebooted.

Searching around the net says things like Docker can interfere, but I don't use anything like that.

I have even went to a older Ubuntu LTS14 server I have sitting over here, and attempted to `ufw` everything, also with no effect.

So, two servers .. zero success..  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you check that you can connect to the web server?

Comment: @AlexP I viewed it in chrome

Comment: On _what computer_? Localhost aka 127.0.0.1 or another computer?

Comment: AlexP has correct question.  From other computer, you can still browse web pages? If yes, on server that offers pages, we need to inspect more carefully the server logs while this is running.  "tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log" for apache.  Leave that terminal open, then run the request again, see what it says. Another idea is to ignore ufw for a minute and run "iptables --list" directly.  Talk directly to iptables, see what it allows, rather than what ufw tells you it allows

Comment: Yeah, if i issue `ufw deny 80` (and 443), i can still load the page from any ol' computer.  `iptables --list` spits out a long list of rules, that I suppose I have to start understanding.  In the past, I used /etc/hosts.* files, in the present I find iptables to be a bit confusing, and in the future I thought `ufw` would be a handy tool, since it uses iptables itself.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out in various testings of `ufw` i apparently made a ton of iptables rules.  `iptables -S` was showing multiple pages of rules.  I reset them with `iptables -X` and `ufw reset` and now am seeing expected results.

Answer (score 1):

For an inner security step, the old /etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow files still work. Examples:

```
#/etc/hosts.deny
# You may wish to enable this to ensure any programs that don't
# validate looked up hostnames still leave understandable logs. In past
# versions of Debian this has been the default.
# ALL: PARANOID
ALL: ALL
```

Then services can be enabled one by one in /etc/hosts.allow.

This is something we did before iptables firewalls existed. It always works
for me, so that even if I flub up the firewall, hosts.deny is there to save me from myself.

To allow in SSH from particular locations, it is easy. Here I allow in my local client and somebody at another random address I picked, plus any ssh users

```
#/etc/hosts.allow
#
ALL: 127.0.0.1
ALL: 112.222.41.120
sshd: ALL
sshdfwd-X11: ALL
```

You can also allow in particular subnets, etc.

Comment: I use that.  I was just trying to learn new stuff...